# How to retrain a pretrained model from PyTorchVideo?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pre-trained-model

I am using the pretrained PyTorchVideo model slowfast_r50_detection as shown [here](https://pytorchvideo.org/docs/tutorial_torchhub_detection_inference). I want to retrain this model with a different private dataset that I have and use it in a similar way as shown in the example. I am new to PyTorch and am not sure how to start retraining such a model. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply load your model first, and than use load_state_dict() function to load the pre-trained model

```py
path_to_saved_model = "Directory/directory/your_saved_model.tar"

video_model = slow_r50_detection(True) 
video_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_saved_model)['model_state_dict'])

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
video_model = video_model.to(device)
```

The model loads the pre-trained weights from the saved model, and anything you run post the load_state_dict() line, the model uses previously trained weights.